# Exit recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, enumeration

I Loop through a complex JSON object but I want to stop the loop after n iterations

```
n = 0;
maxIterations = 100;
ObjectValues = function(v, k){
  if(n == maxIterations){
    if (typeof v == "object") {
      for (var kp in v) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(v, kp)) {
          ObjectValues(v[kp], k != undefined ? k + "." + kp : kp);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log(k + ":" + v);
      n++;
    }
  }else{
    console.log('I should end the function');
    return false;
  }
};
```

But I can't exit the function with return false. The function gets called, even after I tried to exit it with return false.

Comment: try `if(n >= maxIterations)` and let us know.

Comment: n will never be bigger than maxIterations. So this doesn't work. An when i do it like this: n <= maxIterations, then it doesn't work too. But this is not the problem. The problem is, how to exit the function.

Comment: so, are you aware that you don't increase the `n` on your if case?

Comment: I do but just in the else. The function looks through all the objects in a object and if there are no more objects in a object it prints k and v. This information I want to get n times. That's why I increase the n just in the else case.

Comment: So tell us what exactly happens? You say "The function gets called, even after I tried to exit it with return false.", if you can get down to the `return false;` then it means you are already in the function, it is already called. I couldn't understand the question.

Comment: Are you saying even after `return false;` it keeps going? if it is the case, I would say you should make sure that it gets in outer else case buy putting a `console.log("returning false")`. If it logs it, then we will know that js is broken, that you tell it to return and it doesn't :)

Comment: I see the message 'I should end the function' in the log, but the function ObjectValues still runs through the object that I passed into it. I can't make it stop.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to recursively print maxiteration keys and their values:

```
n = 0;
maxIterations = 100;
ObjectValues = function(v, k){
  if(n < maxIterations){
    if (typeof v == "object") {
      for (var kp in v) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(v, kp)) {
          if(! ObjectValues(v[kp], k != undefined ? k + "." + kp : kp) )
            return false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log(k + ":" + v);
      n++;
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('I should end the function');
    return false;
  }
};
```